# discord.py / PRAW: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'hot'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, reddit, praw

I recently created a meme bot, similar to DankMemer. When I run this:

```
    @client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if '!meme' in message.content:
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
        memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
        post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 10)
        for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
            submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

        embed = discord.Embed(title=submission.title)
        embed.set_image(url=submission.url)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

This error appears:

```
C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Nudity/main.py:28: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SubredditHelper.__call__' was never awaited
  memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\Nudity\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/Nudity/main.py", line 28, in on_message
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'hot'
```

How can I fix this?
(Also, I know I could use @client.command but I prefer the Event one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you Async PRAW, since PRAW does not use coroutines.

All of [Async PRAW](https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io/)'s methods are coroutines, and you need to `await` each one.

Since `.subreddit()` is a coroutine, you need to await `.subreddit()`, and then call `.hot()` once it's resolved.

Here is what should be a working example:

```py
meme_subreddit = await reddit.subreddit('memes')
memes_submissions = meme_subreddit.hot()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to await the function:

```py
subreddit = await reddit.subreddit('memes')
memes_submissions = subreddit.hot()
```

You may need some brackets around the whole thing on the right, I can’t remember.

EDITED - Sorry, i didn't test it...

Comment: he needs to await `.subreddit()`, not `.hot()`